# How to check domain name availability via linux command

Tags: php, dns, whois

I am using `checkdnsrr()` function in PHP to check for available or parked domains but the result is not 100% accurate.

Is there any other method to check a domain name availabilty?

Comment: I am looking for domain search functionality

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe phpWhois would be a more reliable source of information?](http://www.phpwhois.org/)

Comment: +1 for phpWhois. I created a similar library for Ruby http://code.simonecarletti.com/whois Here's an example: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/09/ruby-whois-0-8-0/

Answer (score -1):

Use command :- dig [url name]